# PHP Session doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

I tested my app on Chrome, IE and Safari and it works as it should. It was working fine on Mozzila Firefox since two days ago, but I can't figure what which might be the problem.

Here is a part of my js ( I am getting some data from Amazon, using their API and then when someone selects a product, product details should be stored in the session):

```
function redirectStep() {
    window.location.href = Path + "createwidget/step1";
}


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search").click(function() {
            var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
            var page = 1;
            getContent(keyword, page);
        });


        $('#target').on('click', '.click', function() {
            var href_value = $(this).data("href");
            var img_value = $(this).data("img");
            var price_value = $(this).data("price");
            var title_value = $(this).data("t");
            $.post(Path + "createwidget/poststep1", {
                prodlink : href_value,
                prodimg : img_value,
                prodprice : price_value,
                prodtitle : title_value
            });
            redirectStep();
        });

    });
```

Here is a part my controller class (createwidget):

```
  public function poststep1() {
            Session::set('index', $_POST);
            $_SESSION['index']['widfee'] = 10;
            $a = explode("$", $_SESSION['index']['prodprice']);
            $_SESSION['index']['pricy'] = $a[1];
            $_SESSION['index']['totalcost'] = $_SESSION['index']['widfee'] + $_SESSION['index']['pricy'];
        }

public function step1() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['index']['prodtitle'])) {
            $this -> view -> render('createwidget/step1');
        } else {
            $this -> index();
        }
    }
```

I don't know if what I've did is a good practice, but it works in other browsers and it also worked on Firefox. I mention that session_start() exists in my files, and as long as it works on other browsers I really don't see whats the problem.

UPDATE:

Here is the set function:

```
public static function set($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
```

Comment: If it's not working on one browser, the problem has to be server-side

Comment: have you tried to clear your browser's cache? try to clear the cache and close your browser and start again

Comment: Do you get any errors in Firefox?

Comment: Could you be blocking cookies? Check FF to see if it has the PHPSESSID cookie.

Comment: What framework are you using ? Also note that `Session::set()` and `$_SESSION[]` aren't the same things on most frameworks (they don't use PHP's built-in session system and provide their own with `Session::set()` and `Session::get()`).

Comment: @Barmar PHPSESSID => 2a1bbf266a8a2c48b80efcb98f503b7d, so it exists

Comment: @André I've built my own MVC.

Comment: @André here is the set function. public static function set($key, $value) {
  $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I see at least one problem, you're redirecting before you know whether the `$.post` is finished; so you risk going to step 1 before the session variables have been set.

Try setting the redirect function as `success` callback of the post:

```
$.post(Path + "createwidget/poststep1", {
            prodlink : href_value,
            prodimg : img_value,
            prodprice : price_value,
            prodtitle : title_value
        },
        redirectStep);
```